# Generating SHA-256 hash in Python 2.4 using M2Crypto

Tags: python, hash, cryptography, m2crypto, sha256

Is it possible to generate a SHA-256 hash using M2Crypto?  Python 2.4's SHA module doesn't support 256, so I started using PyCrypto, only to find out that PyCrypto doesn't support PKCS#5 (needed elsewhere in my project.)  I switched to M2Crypto as a result and now I would like to replace my PyCrypto SHA-256 call with an M2Crypto equivalent... I tried looking in the unit tests, but didn't see anything.

Answer (score 6):

You could download the `hashlib` module of Python 2.5 (supports SHA256) [for usage on older Pythons](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/hashlib/20081119) (e.g. Python 2.4).